# D-link DSL-2740U does not pick up wireless clients

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I hope someone can help me with our office's wi-fi. I've been reading forums all morning, but basically all they do is tell you how to setup your wi-fi. The setup has already been done and it was working.

We got a new D-Link DSL-2740U last week, did the ADSL setup, checked firmware and finally the wi-fi. Everything worked as it should last week, but after the weekend, typical Monday morning, something has to break.

I checked my phone's settings, restarted the wi-fi, not the router and changed the channel. The phone's errors read **wi-fi connection failure**. The router does not even pick up **wireless clients**.

I've checked google and the best results I get is setup manuals and forums about other routers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may Reset and Re-configure the router. If that doesn't help, it's possible some Wi-Fi receiver component in it may have been burning, such things may happen some time during the first days with new devices, or, maybe due to some possible current outage.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: "You may Reset and Re-configure the router." - How does one do this?  " it's obvious some Wi-Fi receiver component in it may have been burning." - How exactly did you come to this conclusion. I wouldn't say it is obvious this is a hardware problem, cause by overheating component , I personally don't see any evidence of that.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK, checked the rules, will try to follow ...

Comment: @Ramhound OK, Reset -> by the appropriate button, maybe with a pin into a hole, and Re-configure -> same procedure as last week when taking the router in use . And, for my conclusion, have several times seen factory-fresh wireless components dying rightaway or in few days, but of course mostly after years, maybe the wording should have been 'possible' instead of 'obvious'.

Comment: @PeteVfi - You should edit and improve your answer and provide clear concise detailed instructions, the author might not know how to reset or configure their router.  You should explain how to do that..  Just so you know, many of your answers (5+) have appeared in the reivew queue, due to the quality of them.  You really should take the time, to provide concise, detailed relevant instructions, so you answer the author's question.

Answer (score 0):

It bother me that the router did not pick up any more wireless clients, so I did some searching on the router and discovered that the DHCP doesn't resets the IP's for the wireless clients and has a limited range even after you reboot or reconfigure the wifi. I think I understand that correctly. So yes a router reboot (switch the router on and off) will fix it temporally, but you will have to do it weekly.

So I'm going to do a test this week to see if I connect one phone normally and connect another phone with a static IP. If phone one (normal) doesn't connect next week Monday (19 Sept 2016) and the static IP phone does connect, I will report back and provide a detailed description to setup the static IP for Android Phones if it actually works. Hopefully it provides a more permanent solution for people having the same problems with their D-link router.